# HTC Desire 516 dual sim ROOT FAILED (BRICKED?)

Tags: root-access, unbricking, htc-desire, htc

I've tried to root my HTC Desire 516 dual sim by following this guide:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/bootloader-fastboot-recovery-htc-desire-t2845467/page8

But obviously, I did something wrong. Now, when I turn on my phone and unlock the screen, suddenly there is a message saying "Unfortunately, HTC Sense has stopped", and I didn't make a backup and now don't know what to do. Can someone help me to fix it? I cannot do anything on the homescreen or even to get in the app menu, only in settings menu.

Also, when I try to wipe cache or go for the factory reset it returns a string saying "E: failed to mount/sdcard (no such file or directory)"

I tried to find a stock ROM for this phone but seems that there's none on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I just did what you did , i was already ready to brick my phone. 
I received the same error of HTC Sense Stopped.

you can still reach settings menu. just pull the menu from the top of screen , and enter settings. and stay away from home screen as much as possible. thats where htc sense stucks.

from your computer play.google.com and install google go launcher to your phone.

from settings->apps>find htc sense . enter inside do clear cache, data and app defaults.

Now press home button . it will ask which launcher do you want to use . choose google go launcher , ALWAYS!

there you go.